# Why does a method overload or enum flag definition trigger gcc7.2 compiler warning?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, enums, overloading

When compiled in GCC 7.2 (but not 4.4.7!), the following code generates 
a "enum constant in boolean context" (-Wint-in-bool-context) warning.  The warning goes away if I either:

- I remove the other overload (`void func(bool)`)
- I remove the in-enum `FOOBAZ` combination and do the bitwise-OR within the function call (`flagTest.func(Test::FOO | Test::BAZ)`).

My questions are:

- why do either of those changes remove the warning. and/or why is it triggered in the first place?
- other than the above, are there any simple changes I can make to fix the warning?

In the context of my real problem, I can't remove the overload, and the `FOOBAZ` equivalent is used many times (similar to [Qt::AlignCenter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum)).  I've done a lot of searching, but if I've found anything on SO or elsewhere its relevance has escaped me.

```
#include <QFlags>

class Test
{
public:
   enum SimpleFlag
   {
      FOO = 1 << 0,
      BAR = 1 << 1,
      BAZ = 1 << 2,

      FOOBAZ = (FOO | BAZ)
   };
   Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(MyFlags, SimpleFlag)

   Test(){}

   void func(bool) { }
   void func(Test::MyFlags) { }
};

Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(Test::MyFlags)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Q_UNUSED(argc); Q_UNUSED(argv);

   Test flagTest;
   flagTest.func(Test::FOOBAZ);    
}
```

Comment: Because `Test::MyFlags` is not `SimpleFlag`, that's why. Get rid of all the Q-goo, and use just enums, and the code compiles, as expected, without any warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question presents a few interesting issues with overload selection and implicit conversions.

---

First what does `Q_DECLARE_FLAGS` do?  From the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qflags.html#Q_DECLARE_FLAGS), this macro expands to, in this case:

```
typedef QFlags<SimpleFlag> MyFlags;
```

So `MyFlags` is a particular instantiation of the `QFlags` class template provided by Qt.

### Case 1:  Both versions of `func()` and `FOOBAZ` available

When the compiler encounters the call to `func(Test::FOOBAZ)` it takes the type of `FOOBAZ`, and it tries to match that with a function overload.  There are two functions available.

The type of `FOOBAZ` is `SimpleFlag`, which is an enumeration.  `SimpleFlag` implicitly converts to `int`, which can convert to `bool`.  `SimpleFlag` also implicitly converts to `MyFlags` because `QFlags` has a [converting constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qflags.html#QFlags-1).  During overload selection, the conversion to `bool` is preferred over a conversion using a "user-defined" constructor (in `QFlags`).

The compiler selects `func(bool)`, and then warns that `int` is being used like a `bool`.

### Case 2:  Only `func(Test::MyFlags)` available with `FOOBAZ`

Overload resolution proceeds as before, except `func(bool)` is not available.  The compiler selects `func(MyFlags)`.  There is no warning because no integer is being used like a boolean.

### Case 3:  Both versions of `func()` available, but `FOOBAZ` not available

The call is `func(Test::FOO | Test::BAZ)`.  Both `FOO` and `BAZ` have type `SimpleFlag`.  Before looking up which `func()` to use, the compiler searches for overloads of `operator|`.  According to the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qflags.html#Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS) for `Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS`, the macro defines `operator|` for `Test::MyFlags`.  However, in my copy of Qt 5.10.0 it *actually* defines (in qflags.h)

```
QFlags<Test::SimpleFlag> operator|(Test::SimpleFlag, Test::SimpleFlag);
QFlags<Test::SimpleFlag> operator|(Test::SimpleFlag, QFlags<Test::SimpleFlag>);
```

Out of all of the available overloads of `operator|`, the one where both arguments are `Test::SimpleFlag` requires no type conversion.  The compiler selects this one.

The result is a temporary object of type `QFlags<Test::SimpleFlag>`, which is also known as `MyFlags`.  The compiler then has to select a version of `func()` based on an argument of type `MyFlags`.  It chooses `func(MyFlags)` because no type conversion is required.

No warning is issued because an `int` has not been used in a `bool` context.

---

### How To Fix

Scoped enumerations
(`enum class`) were introduced in C++11 in part to prevent issues like this which arise when the enumerators (`FOO`, `BAZ`, etc.) convert to integers in an unwanted manner.  Unfortunately, there is at least [one problem](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47652) where `QFlags` is not compatible with scoped enumerations, at least within the scope of a `QObject`.

The following example will avoid the selecting the `bool` version of `func`, but some tweaking or reworking is probably necessary to make it work with Qt in the real world.  A `static constexpr` variable reintroduces `FOOBAZ` as an identifier in the class scope of `Test`.  The example compiles on GCC 6.4.0 (which also seems to lack the `bool` warning).

```
#include <QFlags>

class Test
{
public:
    enum class SimpleFlag
    {
        FOO = 1 << 0,
        BAR = 1 << 1,
        BAZ = 1 << 2,

        FOOBAZ = (FOO | BAZ)
    };
    Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(MyFlags, SimpleFlag)

    static constexpr SimpleFlag FOOBAZ = SimpleFlag::FOOBAZ;
    Test(){}

    void func(bool) { }
    void func(Test::MyFlags) { }
};

Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(Test::MyFlags)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_UNUSED(argc); Q_UNUSED(argv);

    Test flagTest;
    flagTest.func(Test::FOOBAZ);    
}
```

---

These articles on [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) and [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) were helpful in preparing this answer.

Comment: Great diagnosis.  I should have mentioned in my question that I did try scoped enums (the first thing!) but ran into (I think) https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47652.  So to answer your embedded question, there are issues with scoped enums and Qt5 QFlags.  But I didn't think of declaring a bunch of `static constexpr`, which seems to avoid this issue!  Thanks.

Comment: That's an interesting bug report.  Thanks.  I've edited some of this information into the answer.